# Statistical characteristics of low complexity subshifts

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics

I am looking for calculations of statistical characteristics (variance, entropy, etc.) of the $n$-dimensional distributions of the invariant measures of low complexity subshifts (e.g., the Sturmian or the Thue - Morse subshifts). I am aware of the works on finding the factor frequencies in these situations, on which these calculations can be based. However I would prefer to see them done explicitly.

Comment: One might find it among papers that are about ergodic optimization where people are interested in low complexity; e.g. you can look at Bousch's paper (the title is fish and is french).

Comment: @Adam - Le poisson n'a pas d'arêtes? Do not see how it would be related (and I do realize that my question is about ergodic theory of low complexity subshifts)